# Aptos move compilation error: Duplicate definition for module

Tags: aptos, move-lang

I set up an Aptos local testnet and try to publish a module using Aptos move CLI, but it always fail on compilation with an error: duplicate declaration, item, or annotation. Duplicate definition for module.
However, the move source code only contains one module and I never publish any module on this account before...
Many thanks!!

My module is like this:

```
module my_addr::repeated_call{
    fun do_nothing(){
    }
    public entry fun repeat_n_calls(n: u64){
        let i = 0;
        while(i < n){
            i = i + 1;
            do_nothing();
        }
    }
}
```

and the Move.toml:

```
[package]
name = 'repeated_call'
version = '1.0.0'
[dependencies.AptosFramework]
git = 'https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core.git'
rev = 'main'
subdir = 'aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework'
[addresses]
# this is my account address
my_addr = '0x4050d8d4b513983cb4cb917d18cbc68274010ae6ce09fa826eca8caf9ebf7dd1'
```

error message:

```
error[E02001]: duplicate declaration, item, or annotation
  ┌─ /home/featurize/move-packages/repeated_call/sources/repeated_call.move:1:17
  │
1 │ module my_addr::repeated_call{
  │                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  │                 │
  │                 Duplicate definition for module '(my_addr=0x4050D8D4B513983CB4CB917D18CBC68274010AE6CE09FA826ECA8CAF9EBF7DD1)::repeated_call'
  │                 Module previously defined here, with '(my_addr=0x4050D8D4B513983CB4CB917D18CBC68274010AE6CE09FA826ECA8CAF9EBF7DD1)::repeated_call'

{
  "Error": "Move compilation failed: Compilation error"
}
```

No module published on this account before:

```
aptos account list --query modules --account 0x4050d8d4b513983cb4cb917d18cbc68274010ae6ce09fa826eca8caf9ebf7dd1 --profile user0
{
  "Result": []
}
```

- aptos-move 1.0.14
- rustc 1.66.1 (90743e729 2023-01-10)
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Do you have multiple files in your `sources/` directory? This error seems like the kind of error you get when you define the same module multiple times in the same package.